# update a specific word in column

Tags: oracle, t-sql, sap-ase

I have this column

> column
>   London/paris 
>   toronto/paris
>   Tokyo/paris

I want to update only the word 'paris'

My desirable result:

> column
>   London/turkey
>   toronto/turkey
>   Tokyo/turkey

Can I have a condition like if next to paris is toronto I update it to berlin?

EDIT.
I want to know the queries in oracle or sybase. (I am not sure if I can ask this question separated in ora and syb, I hope a moderator give me an advice about that)

Comment: what if a row has something like `parish/bla`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the replace function for TSQL to do this

```
UPDATE myTable
SET MyColumn = REPLACE(MyColumn, 'paris', 'turkey')
WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%paris%'
```

Comment: TSQL is supported by Sybase-ASE so this should work on sybase

Comment: Both Oracle and Sybase have a REPLACE() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
update #t set col1 = str_replace(col1, 'paris', 'turkey')
```

Comment: This is almost identical to the earlier answer, but less efficient as you're going to update everything whether it needs it or not.